# html блок как переменная

Tags: php

Как правильно сохранить html блок и использовать его как переменную в других файлах?
Задача автоматизировать добавление некоторых кусков html кода в другие страницы - по типу конструктора. Мне понятна модель использования БД, но выглядит это грязно.

Comment: вынесите разметку в отдельный файл и делайте инклуд, где надо?

Comment: Спасибо за реакцию! Будет ли это работать, если в инклуд включены php функции которые должны работать в итоге в основном файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы не писать везде один и тот же код, нужно вынести повторяющийся код в отдельный файл(так часто делают для подключения к базе данных), нужно использовать `include` — 
`include "вашфайл.php";`
Вот что говорит [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php):

> Выражение `include` включает и выполняет указанный файл.
>
> Файлы включаются исходя из пути указанного файла, или, если путь не
>   указан, используется путь, указанный в директиве `include_path`. Если
>   файл не найден в `include_path`, `include` попытается проверить
>   директорию, в которой находится текущий включающий скрипт и текущую
>   рабочую директорию перед тем, как выдать ошибку. Конструкция `include`
>   выдаст предупреждение, если не сможет найти файл; поведение отлично от
>   `require`, который выдаст фатальную ошибку.
>
> Если путь указан — абсолютный (начинающийся с буквы диска или с \ в
>   Windows или с / в Unix/Linux системах) или относительно текущей
>   директории (начинающийся с . или ..) — `include_path` будет
>   проигнорирован вообще. Например, если имя файла начинается с ../,
>   парсер будет искать в родительской директории запрошенный файл.